# AMFPHP over SSL problem

Tags: php, flash, remoting, amfphp

I seem to be having a problem running AMFPHP under SSL in our development environment.

I created a self-signed cert under CentOS and got everything working, but whenever I go to the page in Firefox I get warned that the certificate is self-certified and therefore cannot be accepted.

This then seems to affect the AMFPHP calls from flash saying that the certificate was not accepted on the call... Does anyone know a way round this? Is it a setting we can edit locally? Is there something in the AMFPHP config that will ignore this? Or is this happening at a lower level?

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the certificate as a trusted source but that will only help you on your browser and won't improve the overal experience.  Unless it will be fine your you to inform your users to do this (as it is a one off action).

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure you are using the SecureAMFEndPoint in stead of the regular AMFEndPoint on the ActionScript side.